# Opacity Transition Mapbox Fade In

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, transparency-opacity

I am facing a problem using the 'fill-opacity-transition' in Mapbox GL JS. Maybe someone has an idea what the mistake could be?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Add GeoJSON Flood Polygons</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
        <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.52.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
        <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.52.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <style>
            body { margin:0; padding:0; }
            #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id='map'></div>
    <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2xrMTg0IiwiYSI6ImNqcWlkcDRzMzBkZmc0OW55eDR4cTM4YXQifQ.zPkBQsqBwXVfMZLlsRq7AQ';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9',
        center: [7.5, 50.5],
        zoom: 5
    });

    map.on('load', function () {

        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'maine',
            'type': 'fill',
            'source': {
                'type': 'geojson',
                'data': {
                    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
                    "name": "Flood_2017_GEOJSON",
                    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4030" } },
                    'features': [
                        { 
                        'type': 'Feature',
                        "properties": { 
                            "ID": 4433, 
                            "GlideNumbe": null, 
                            "Country": "Germany", 
                            "OtherCount": null, 
                            "long": 9.583276, 
                            "lat": 54.705274, 
                            "Area": 18991.845394600001, 
                            "Began": "2017-01-02", 
                            "Ended": "2017-01-05", 
                            "Validation": "News", 
                            "Dead": 0, 
                            "Displaced": 0, 
                            "MainCause": "Winter Storm Axel", 
                            "Severity": 1.5 
                        },
                        'geometry': {
                            'type': 'MultiPolygon',
                            'coordinates': [ [ [ 
                                [ 13.532608, 54.306792 ], 
                                [ 13.33466, 53.662268 ], 
                                [ 10.414927, 53.415802 ], 
                                [ 9.425187, 54.457616 ], 
                                [ 9.227239, 55.251098 ], 
                                [ 9.524161, 55.994746 ], 
                                [ 9.920057, 55.944961 ], 
                                [ 9.623135, 54.953381 ], 
                                [ 10.019031, 54.407731 ], 
                                [ 10.761336, 54.109839 ], 
                                [ 11.058258, 53.911344 ], 
                                [ 12.493381, 54.009796 ], 
                                [ 13.532608, 54.306792 ] 
                                ] ] ]
                            }
                        },
                        { 
                        "type": "Feature", 
                        "properties": { 
                            "ID": 4487, 
                            "GlideNumbe": null, 
                            "Country": "Chile", 
                            "OtherCount": null, 
                            "long": -70.99118, 
                            "lat": -33.418779, 
                            "Area": 71430.431284100006, 
                            "Began": "2017-06-14", 
                            "Ended": "2017-06-20", 
                            "Validation": "News", 
                            "Dead": 4, 
                            "Displaced": 50, 
                            "MainCause": "Heavy Rain", 
                            "Severity": 1.0 
                        }, 
                        "geometry": { 
                            "type": "MultiPolygon", 
                            "coordinates": [ [ [ 
                                [ -70.248875, -31.187761 ], 
                                [ -70.347849, -30.691847 ], 
                                [ -70.149901, -32.477059 ], 
                                [ -70.050927, -33.766357 ], 
                                [ -70.644771, -36.146209 ], 
                                [ -71.931433, -35.550525 ], 
                                [ -71.733485, -34.360549 ], 
                                [ -71.337589, -30.691349 ], 
                                [ -70.248875, -31.187761 ] 
                                ] ] ]
                            }
                        },
                        { 
                        "type": "Feature", 
                        "properties": { 
                            "ID": 4491, 
                            "GlideNumbe": null, 
                            "Country": "France", 
                            "OtherCount": null, 
                            "long": 3.338286, 
                            "lat": 45.485499, 
                            "Area": 45514.498247099997, 
                            "Began": "2017-06-13", 
                            "Ended": "2017-06-15", 
                            "Validation": "News", 
                            "Dead": 1, 
                            "Displaced": 160, 
                            "MainCause": "Torrential Rain", 
                            "Severity": 2.0 
                        }, 
                        "geometry": { 
                            "type": "MultiPolygon", 
                            "coordinates": [ [ [ 
                                [ 5.070331, 45.137548 ], 
                                [ 2.497008, 44.246285 ], 
                                [ 1.606242, 46.230191 ], 
                                [ 4.278539, 46.724713 ], 
                                [ 5.070331, 45.137548 ] 
                                ] ] ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            'layout': {},
            'paint': {
                'fill-color': [
                      'interpolate',
                      ['linear'],
                      ['number', ['get', 'Severity']],
                      1.0, 'rgb(246, 249, 24)',
                      1.5, 'rgb(216, 0, 0)',
                      2.0, 'rgb(229, 0, 206)'
                    ],
                'fill-opacity': 0,
                'fill-opacity-transition': {duration: 2000}
                }
        });
    });

    // so after the map is initialized we call a function which rund as example after 3 seconds and set the opacity value to 0.8
    // the circle-opacity-transition is set as 2000, what means that changes to this value takes 2 seconds

    setTimeout(function() {
      map.setPaintProperty('geojson', 'fill-opacity', 0.8);
        }, 
        3000
    );
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

My polygons are not fading in after the defined 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not working because you need to specify the correct layer for `map.setPaintProperty` (`maine` instead of `geojson`).

```
setTimeout(function() {
      map.setPaintProperty('maine', 'fill-opacity', 0.8);
        }, 
        3000
    );
```

Docs: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setpaintproperty